# Giving a text link a background image?

Tags: html, css

everyone. I'm trying to give a text link a background image but I'm not having any luck, I've got no image appearing. I was wondering if someone one could tell me if my code is wrong and what I can do to correct it. Thanks for any help in advance.

Here's my css code, hlink and home are ids, and home is my positioning of my link text

```
#hlink:link{
        background-image: url("../media/taboff.gif");
        color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;
}

#hlink:visited{
        color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;
}

#hlink:hover{
        /*background-image:url("../media/tab2.gif");*/
        text-decoration:underline;
        color:#EF504B;
}

#hlink:active{
        text-decoration:underline;
        color:#EF504B;
}

#home{
        position:absolute;
        font-size:2em;
        top:270px;
        left:300px;
        text-align:center;
```

and here is my html code

```
<div id="home">
        <a id="hlink" href="midterm.html">Home</a>
</div>
```

Edit: I just want to say thank you all so much for helping me, every single one of you have saved my life, I don't know if edits notify everyone who has answered, but again, thanks so much. Aside from some missing code, my biggest problem was with the image itself that I was using so that's my next issue to correct. I tested out a different image and it worked 100% so thanks for that everyone. I'm also relatively new to this, I'm a freshman in college and have only been doing this for a few weeks(I also have a terrible professor but that's another story for another time) but I'm glad to have found such a helpful community, hopefully one day I'll be able to contribute myself.

Comment: BTW, you have included more code than is needed to show your problem. In the future, consider paring it back to the absolute minimum code needed to show the problem, and including a working example of your problem via http://jsfiddle.net That said: welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GTHyU/

My guess is that perhaps you have made your `url()` relative to your HTML page instead of your CSS file? Try it with an absolute URL first and see if it starts working, then figure out the appropriate relative path you need based on the location of the CSS file.

Comment: +1: OP should be using absolute paths from within a CSS file.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Why do you suggest absolute paths instead of simply making them properly relative to the source?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, and my relative url was working but it was my image that was giving me the real problem.

Comment: in my experience paths to style sheets may change over time depending on how often one messes with a site. I'm not sure if this is a personal site of his or a business site, but the use of absolute paths removes any ambiguity for the next person who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
#hlink{
        background:transparent url(../media/taboff.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
        color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/nh7nY/

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles to each link:

```
display: block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
```

That should make the background-image appear. You can change the height and width to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#hlink:link {background:url(images/media_library.png) no-repeat top left}
```